# How to get specific columns returned by stored procedure in variable/list using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.2

I want to get list of specific columns returned by stored procedure.In the result set two column names will be common and one column name will be dynamic.

```
ALTER PROC DBO.GETLANGUAGETRANSLATION(@LANGCODE VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(255)
SET @QUERY= N'SELECT RESOURCENAME,ENText,'+UPPER(@LANGCODE)+' INTO #TEMP FROM DBO.LANGUAGETRANSLATION SELECT * FROM #TEMP';
EXEC(@QUERY);
END
```

RESOURCENAME and ENText column will be same in output each time but based in input parameter third column name will vary.

I am writing below code in C# using Entity Framework Core LINQ

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<LanguageTranslation>> GetAsync(string langCode)
        {
            var context = new LQMSDbContext(AppConstants.DB_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY);
            try
            {
                string query = "GetLanguageTranslation '" + langCode + "'";
                var result = context.LanguageTranslation.FromSql(query).ToList();
                var result1 = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GETLANGUAGETRANSLATION @p0", parameters: langCode );
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string a = ex.Message;
            }


            return await _dbSet
            .Where(x => x.Equals(langCode))
             .ToListAsync();
        }
```

I am trying to call stored procedure **GETLANGUAGETRANSLATION** using two different approaches. But both are failing with below error

> The required column 'ESText' was not present in the results of a
>   'FromSql' operation

Where ESText refers to the column which I am not returning from stored procedure but present in table.

I want to store only few columns in result set in c# and not all.

Can any body help me in this?

NOTE : It works fine with `Select * from LanguageTranslation` query

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how to execute raw queries. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

You can write the query to store the results temporarily in a temp table then select from that table.

FromSql takes more parameters for your injection, you will want to use those extra parameters to place yours into the query. Don't string concatenate.

Another note: when you use ToList or ToArray or Count you will execute the query on the server.